# Почему не могу залить на github?

Tags: git, github

В корне проекта нажимаю git bush,далее в комм.строке ввожу все комманды,нажимаю enter.В результате на github в репозитории только файл Readme.md.А моих папок с кодом и картинками нет.В коммандной строке пишет:
Untracked files:
        images/
        index.html
        styles/

Comment: Видимо, не все команды вводите...

Comment: Ввожу по подсказке:echo "# landing" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/Aleksandrwm/landing.git
git push -u origin master

Comment: Ну, всё верно. Вы же выясняли, что эти команды означают?

Comment: Нет,после этих комманд у меня в репозитории только файл Readme.md,а должны быть еще папки:styles,images и файл index.html.А их нет,не заливаются...не пойму почему.

Comment: Вы кроме README.md ни одного файла и не добавили. Попробуйте не просто копировать команды "по подсказке", а узнать, что они означают и как ими пользоваться.

Answer (score 3):

У вас не получится бездумно копировать команды и использовать git

Нужно знать минимальный набор команд и хорошо понимать, что они делают. Учтите, контроль версий - это обоюдоострый самурайский меч, может спасти вам жизнь, и может и ноги поотрубать. И не только ноги.

Команды:

- `git status` - показывает, что происходит. Текущее положение, состояние, измененные файлы, новые файлы и так далее. Рекомендуется выполнять прежде, чем вообще что-то сделать
- `git add` - добавляет файлы в репозиторий. По умолчанию новые файлы не отслеживаются. После добавления - отслеживаются. Добавлять можно по одному файлу или целыми папками, или вообще все что рядом лежит `*`
- `git commit` - закрепляет текущее рабочее положение как хорошее. Ставит точку на ветке. Сохраняет состояние репозитория
- `git pull` - слить с удаленного сервера все изменения к себе. Удаленные ветки помечаются обычно origin/, а локальный - просто . Например при клонировании проекта у вас появляется ветки origin/master и master, и это не обязательно одно и то же
- `git push` - залить на удаленный сервер. Позволяет вам передать на удаленный сервер все, что вы наделали

Еще стоит посмотреть команды `git checkout`, `git branch` и `git reset`

Упрощенная схема работы:

1. Встать в папку проекта
2. Сделать `git pull` - получаем все изменения с сервера
3. Сделать `git status` - смотрим, все ли в порядке, на той ли мы ветке работаем и т.д.
4. Пишем код, добавляем файлы, пьем кофе, пишем код, отлаживаем
5. Смотрим `git status`
6. Добавляем все необходимые файлы в отслеживаемые `git add`
7. Делаем `git commit`
8. Делаем `git push` на удаленный сервер

Это очень упрощенный алгоритм. Обычно сюда вклиниваются еще `git merge`, `git diff` и `git checkout`. Зависит от сложности проекта и методологии разработки. И вашей роли в проекте.